# Abertura do SQLite3 no Windows10

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

Quando abro o SQLite3 no Windows 10, ele simplesmente abre o prompt de comando, dando a permissão de comando frente a linha **sqlite>**.

Já no windows 7 e 8 ele abre normalmente.

Meu intuito de utilizar o SQLite é para uma simples conexão de uma aplicação básica feita em Java.

Comment: Ué, mas o SQLite3 é em linha de comando, você pode usar algum outro aplicativo de interface para manipular as bases sqlite, como o próprio eclipse, ou o SQuirreL. Mas o programa oficial do SQLite3 é em linha de comando mesmo.

Comment: O que você quis dizer com "abre normalmente"?

Comment: Oi Julio, no windows 7 eu consigo utilizar a interface gráfica dele, normalmente...